# React Native on click show options

Tags: reactjs, react-native, drop-down-menu, dropdown

[image: state before click]
[image: state after click]

In android cell phones contact page there are a **three dots** icon on the top right-hand corner (**first image**). When clicked, a menu will show up (**second image**).

I have searched, but couldn't find any third party package for this behavior. I don't want to use **Picker** or something similar.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use some package like that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-menu

Here is simple snippet how to use this package:

```
import React from 'react';


import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Menu, { MenuItem, MenuDivider } from 'react-native-material-menu';

class App extends React.PureComponent {
  _menu = null;

  setMenuRef = ref => {
    this._menu = ref;
  };

  hideMenu = () => {
    this._menu.hide();
  };

  showMenu = () => {
    this._menu.show();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Menu
          ref={this.setMenuRef}
          button={<Text onPress={this.showMenu}>Show menu</Text>}
        >
          <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Menu item 1</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Menu item 2</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu} disabled>
            Menu item 3
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuDivider />
          <MenuItem onPress={this.hideMenu}>Menu item 4</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```